# Xpath for element on Android mobile app

Tags: android, xml, xpath, webdriver, appium

I am struggling to write `Xpath` of an element present in Android mobile app -

Below is xml:

```
<node index="5" text="" resource-id="com.mcdonalds.app:id/grid_item" class="android.widget.RelativeLayout" package="com.mcdonalds.app" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[366,601][714,949]">
                        <node index="0" text="Buy one Big Mac, get one FREE&#13;" resource-id="com.mcdonalds.app:id/name" class="android.widget.TextView" package="com.mcdonalds.app" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[378,841][702,907]" />
                        <node index="1" text="Expires 12/31/15" resource-id="com.mcdonalds.app:id/expiration" class="android.widget.TextView" package="com.mcdonalds.app" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[378,907][702,937]" />
                    </node>
```

I am trying to click the element which has property `text="Buy one Big Mac, get one FREE&#13;"`

The xpath I have tried are -

```
driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.TextView[@text='Buy one Big Mac, get one FREE&#13;']").click();
```

AND

```
driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.TextView[@text=\"Buy one Big Mac, get one FREE&#13;\"]").click();
```

Both of the methods do not work. Does anyone had similar issue?

There is no other unique property of the element.

Comment: <node index="0" text="Buy one Big Mac, get one FREE&#13;" resource-id="com.mcdonalds.app:id/name" class="android.widget.TextView" package="com.mcdonalds.app" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[378,841][702,907]" />

Comment: I suspect the encoded is causing trouble here. You can try using XPath `starts-with()`, if it is supported in appium : `//android.widget.TextView[starts-with(@text='Buy one Big Mac, get one FREE')]`

Comment: Thanks buddy. I tried but I am receiving error as org.apache.xpath.functions.FuncStartsWith only allows 2 arguments :(

Comment: Ah the error message suggests that `starts-with()` function is supported in the XPath processor, only the number of args passed was wrong (and indeed I was giving a wrong example, check my answer for possible solutions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `=` in my comment should've been a comma (`,`) to make it valid XPath expression, like so :

```
//android.widget.TextView[starts-with(@text, 'Buy one Big Mac, get one FREE')]
```

or in case the `&#13;` is considered a white space by the XPath processor that you use, then you can use `normalize-space()` to clean it up first :

```
//android.widget.TextView[normalize-space(@text) = 'Buy one Big Mac, get one FREE']
```

Comment: //android.widget.TextView[normalize-space(@text) = 'Buy one Big Mac, get one FREE'] - this worked :)

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need xpath!! Just use name and click on it. Like this:

```
driver.findElementByName("Buy one Big Mac, get one FREE&#13").click();
```

Comment: Thanks Gaurav; it does work when the element text is like "Buy one Big Mac, get one FREE" but when the text is "Buy one Big Mac, get one FREE&#13" it doesn't special character string "&#13" is causing issue which is basically code for new line in xml

Answer (score -1):

Since the element has a clear cut resource id use that .. Its much more reliable

```
driver.findElementBy(By.id("com.mcdonalds.app:id/name"))
```

And then you get the text and verify if needed.

Comment: Thanks Shamik I have around 4-5 objects with the same resource-id. the text in the object is the only unique property.